# Caliburn Micro How to get selected items list for list box and other similar controls

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

I can get the value of a single selected item but I just cannot find any way to get a list of all selected items. Can anyone help? I am using Windows Store Apps if that makes a difference.

```
<ListBox x:Name="TestList" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Multiple"  />
<Button   x:Name="but1" Width="100" Height="100" Content="Click Me" Grid.Row="0"   HorizontalAlignment="Right" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action SayHello(TestList.SelectedItems)]" </Button>
```

I have a listbox with SelectionMode="Multiple". When I click on button "but1", I want to pass a list of all items selected to SayHello. If I pass in TestList.SelectedItem, the first item selected is passed in ok. But if I use TestList.SelectedItems, a null is passed to SayHello. How do I pass the entire selected list?

In my ViewModel class, I have the following subroutine.

```
    public void SayHello(object item)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Could you please show your work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to pass the SelectedItems property as an argument to the method, but you could always manually bind the SelectedItems property to a VM property with the appropriate collection type and reference that property from your method.  Since this does not really answer your question, I would have posted it as a commend instead, but for some reason StackOverflow won't let new users comment.

Comment: I would if I could but SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}" just gives me an error. I can enter SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" without any problem.

Comment: What is the error?  If you have a public IEunumerable<ListItemType> SelectedItems { get; set; } property defined on your VM where ListItemType is the data type of the items in the list, it works fine - I do this all the time.

Comment: The error is in the XAML - "The property "SelectedItems" does not have an accessible setter.".

Comment: You need a public setter on any properties that you want CM to update.

Comment: Do I need SelectedItems to be a dependency property? I believe it may not be.